# How to reflectively access generic type parameter annotations of record components?

Tags: java, reflection, record

I've got the program at the end of this question and I want to reflectively access the `@Annot` annotation. However, while I can do so for classes, I can't get access to the annotation if it is used in a record component. Running the code outputs

```
[@tmp.Test$Annot()]
[]
```

I've tried adding all types defined in `ElementType` enum to the `Targets` array, but it still doesn't work. Calling `getDeclaredAnnotations` doesn't work either. Is there any way to actually access this annotation? The decompiled code looks like this:

```java
public static final class C {
    List<@Test.Annot String> strings;
    public C() {}
}
public static record R(List<String> strings) {
    public R(List<@Test.Annot String> strings) { this.strings = strings; }
    public List<@Test.Annot String> strings() { return this.strings; }
}
```

```java
public final class Test {
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Annot {}

    public static final class C {
        List<@Annot String> strings;
    }

    public record R(List<@Annot String> strings) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            Field field = C.class.getDeclaredFields()[0];
            AnnotatedParameterizedType type = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) field.getAnnotatedType();
            AnnotatedType argument = type.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(argument.getAnnotations()));
        }
        {
            RecordComponent component = R.class.getRecordComponents()[0];
            AnnotatedParameterizedType type = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) component.getAnnotatedType();
            AnnotatedType argument = type.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(argument.getAnnotations()));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This seems to be a bug in the JDK... As soon as I annotate the list itself:

```java
public record R(@Annot List<@Annot String> strings) {}
```

the decompiled code becomes:

```java
public static record R(@Test.Annot List<@Test.Annot String> strings) ...
```

Now, both, the list as well as the type parameter are annotated.

**EDIT 2:** Confirmed to be a bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8292159

Comment: I agree that it is a compiler bug, but I can't seem to find a bug report for this... I am using OpenJDK 17. What JDK are you using? I ask because if JDKs from different vendors are exhibiting the same behaviour, then it's likely not a bug.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm using the JDK I downloaded from Oracle. I tried compiling with both javac `17.0.1` and `18.0.1.1`.

Comment: @Sweeper I tried to find some information in the JLS and JVM specs but couldn't find anything that defines this specific behavior (I cannot claim to fully understand the latter, although [it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se18/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.20) was an interesting read). Anyway, I submitted a bugreport earlier today.